# Text split issue in XML

Tags: xml

Am facing issue of line split in xml file. The line which is present as single line in docx is split into 2 or 3 text tags in xml. Please find the sample xml paragraphs below for better approach of the problem.
 As per docx, the lines are like: 
"Do not use This tablet if you:
   •    are allergic (hypersensitive) to This tablet or any other medicines containing this chemical or any of the other ingredients of this Tablet."

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

XMl sample paragraph is below:

```
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
            <w:autoSpaceDE w:val="false"/>
            <w:rPr></w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Times-Bold" w:ascii="Times-Bold" w:hAnsi="Times-Bold"/>
                <w:b/>
                <w:bCs/>
                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Do not use </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>This tablet if you:</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Times-Roman" w:ascii="Times-Roman" w:hAnsi="Times-Roman"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t>
            <w:br/>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
            <w:numPr>
                <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
                <w:numId w:val="12"/>
            </w:numPr>
            <w:autoSpaceDE w:val="false"/>
            <w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="360"/>
            <w:rPr></w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Times-Roman" w:ascii="Times-Roman" w:hAnsi="Times-Roman"/>
                <w:color w:val="000000"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">are allergic (hypersensitive) to </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>This tablet or any other medicines containing this chemical or any of the other ingredients of this Tablet.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Comment: Did you also have a question?

Comment: A single line in a docx file will be split into multiple XML elements if there is any change in formatting, such as bolded, italicized, or colored text. If you want it all in the same element, you need to make sure that it's all formatted the same. In your case, `Do not use` is a bolded font while the rest isn't.

Comment: As per Docx "Do not use This tablet if you:" is in BOLD and remaining text isn't..